# Using Webform Hooks to submit and display custom module forms?

Tags: forms, hooks, webforms

So i created my custom module form and submit handler...then realized i needed to use Webform hooks to save and hopefully view. Basically i wish for webform to manage the heavy lifting by taking care of the save and submissions.. also is it possible to save the values from the form as nodes or send them as emails? please any help is appreciated iv been staring at the webform API for days..

Answer (score 1):

Webform has nothing to do with your form if you created it in a module.Your form is a form not a webform type node.
[Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)! reference is what you need and to install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module

Then

```
dpm($form)
```

inside your form builder function to check which function is your #submit which is your #validate and add[] your own if you like

form values are stored in $form_state array
dpm($form_state) it also in your submit function and do whatever you want with these submitted values.

Store them in drupal database using [variable_set()](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.drupal.org%2Fvariable_set&ei=rQgUUaaMCMfLswaFsoCoDQ&usg=AFQjCNGUgKleihszsq-BhRJIjNrfxAjl4g&sig2=yT6mzPgaTOBHruHUbUIjTw&bvm=bv.42080656,d.Yms) , mail them using drupal_mail() etc.

Some links

http://drupal.org/node/717740
http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example%21form_example_tutorial.inc/7